# How to add import in "Implemented Method Body" in IntelliJ IDEA: Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Template -> Implemented Method Body?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-idea-2016

I set Java's "Implemented Method Body" (Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Template -> Implemented Method Body) to `throw new NotImplementedException();`.

But `NotImplementedException` requires `import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException;`.

So how can I add this import automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fully qualified name of the exception class in the template; IntelliJ IDEA will automatically shorten it and add the necessary import.

Note that this `NotImplementedException` is from an internal JDK package, so it's unlikely to be a good idea to use it in your code. You should find a more suitable class from the public JDK API, such as `UnsupportedOperationException`.